# Is it possible to insert the values from a submitted Form Builder form into a specific contact by modifying the form's URL?

Tags: formbuilder

I've built a form using Form Builder. The form asks for details needed for a police background check but it doesn't ask for the applicant's name or email because it's assumed a contact has already been created into the database for the applicant. My idea is to email a link to the form and modify the URL somehow so that when the form is submitted its contents gets attached to the right contact. The right contact would be determined using a token set in the message template. **Is this possible?**

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't spotted the "Accept ID from URL" checkbox until now. This seems to do the trick.

[image]